# Explorer not starting after logon script ran

Tags: windows, batch-file, login-script, group-policy

I set a batch script to run at logon using GPO that runs an exe. The exe runs, but Explorer doesn't start until after I stop the exe

For example, say this is my batch file:

```
notepad.exe
```

This will open notepad on a black background; no task bar, no desktop.  When I close notepad, the task bar and desktop icons come up.  If I change the batch file to this:

```
notepad.exe
explorer
```

at logon, notepad opens up and the task bar and desktop icons appear.

I've checked GPO settings to make sure logon scripts are being run asynchronously so I'm not sure what's going on. Can anyone help me with this?

For clarification, I'm not trying to run notepad at startup, I'm trying to run a synchronization program that doesn't have a UI so when I start it using the batch script, I just get a black screen because I guess the logon process is waiting for the exe to 'finish' or close to start explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
start "" notepad.exe
```

You can place a window-title between the `"` if you like.